# Understanding summations with Poisson

Tags: probability, summation

I'm currently doing a problem on Poisson processes and I've encountered the situation where I'm not sure why this summation is expanded as follows:
[image]

And similarly
[image]

I have tried expanding out the left hand side to try and get a better understanding of what is going on, and I to some extent understand that it should be half of the poisson distribution plus another term, but I'm not sure how we get the second term or why it is that term.

Hopefully what I'm asking makes sense. I'm a bit confused!

Thank you!

Comment: It would probably be easier for you to try to get the LHS from the RHS (instead of expanding the LHS to the RHS).

Comment: For the first line. Check that you actually cancel all odd terms and have double the amount of even terms, hence the $1/2$ in front.

Comment: In the first one the lhs is the sum of the even terms. In the right hand one if n is even your terms in the sum add and if n is odd they subtract (and vanish) so it is also the sum of the even terms. The second is similar but for odd terms.

Comment: I think they are doing that to break the sum up into two familiar sums.  It's hard to say exactly without seeing where they go next.

Comment: This really helps everyone! I tried understanding it from the right hand side like you guys said and I see what is happening.

@GregoryGrant - the purpose was to be able to use the Taylor expansion for the exponential to simplify the expression so that it no longer had summations in it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your first equation is just like $\cosh(x)=\frac{\exp(x)+\exp(-x)}{2}$ (isolating the even power terms in the exponential) and your second is just like $\sinh(x)=\frac{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)}{2}$ (isolating the odd power terms in the exponential).

If you haven't seen this before, start from the series for $\exp(x)$ and $\exp(-x)$. Note that if you add the two series, you get a series with only even terms, and if you subtract the two series, you get a series with only odd terms. Then the constant factor is just to rescale appropriately (the even terms got doubled when you added, while the odd terms got doubled when you subtracted).

I first encountered this trick when studying Euler's formula, where the relevant "$x$" is $i \theta$. Then $\cosh(i \theta)=\cos(\theta)$ and $\sinh(i \theta)=i\sin(\theta)$.